# Cloudant user managent

Tags: android, authentication, cloudant

I plan to use Cloudant for data storing and synchronization across multiple user's Android devices. I am new to Cloudant and looking for best practice how to create user account from client device and get "read" "write" permissions to some database. Of course docs created by one user may not be accessible by another. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would create some server side process that has "admin" access to your Cloudant account. When a new user is registered in your app, your server-side script is instructed to create a user and it will:

- [create a database](https://docs.cloudant.com/database.html#create)
- [generate an API key](https://docs.cloudant.com/authorization.html#creating-api-keys)
- [grant read/write access to the database for that API key](https://docs.cloudant.com/authorization.html#modifying-permissions)
- pass those credentials back to the client
- optionally create a record in a database which records a record per user that indicates to you who the user is, which database they are assigned to etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the set up I have seen, the permissions are  set up at the database level. Once you got access, you can see all the documents/designdocs. It will be nice if we can set up permissions at designdoc level to avoid unintentional mistakes.